# angular 4 child routing

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to write routing for childs. The problem Im having is with path not beeing inserted in url bar of thhe browser properly. Below the code.

router.module

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'upload', component: DrawingUploadComponent },
      { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent },
      { path: 'projects', component: ProjectListComponent }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class MenuRoutingModule {}
```

menu.component

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/projects" routerLinkActive="active">Projects</a>
  <a routerLink="/upload" routerLinkActive="active">Upload</a>
  <a routerLink="/account" routerLinkActive="active">Account</a>
</nav>
MENU COMPONENT
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the parent component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent},
  {path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

So the problem is when im under `"/menu"` the menu component is displayed, now when Im clicking on any link e.g

```
<a routerLink="/upload" routerLinkActive="active">Upload</a>
```

im getting console error 
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'upload'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'upload'

but when i'd type the route by hand in browser bar "/menu/upload" I'm getting the proper result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your route starts with `/`, that refers to the root of your app.  You'll need to remove that, or else use the full path e.g. `routerLink="/menu/upload"`.